# Geometry and natural numbers

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

I can't find the solution to the following problem, any help welcome.

One is given a natural number N. One has to find N points on a straight line, and a (N+1)th point which is not on this straight line, such that the distance (in cm, say) between any pair of points is a natural number (not necessarily the same natural number for different pairs of points).

The difficulty is to find a solution for any N. In the particular case N=3, one solution is the following. Place 3 points A, B and C on a straight line, such that the distances AB = 4cm and BC = 4cm. On the bissection of AC, place a point D such that the distance BD = 3cm. Then AD = CD = 5cm and the problem is solved.

Comment: Here's another solution for $n=3$: The first two Pythagorean triples are $(3,4,5)$ and $(5,12,13)$. Put $A$ at the origin, $D$ on the $y$-axis at $y=3\times5$, and $B$ and $C$ on the $x$-axis with $x=4\times\frac{3\times5}3$ and $x=12\times\frac{3\times5}5$ respectively. Generalize this method.

Answer (score 1):

First we simplify the problem by noticing that by applying a rotation and translation we can assume that the straight line is the x-axis and the $(N+1)$-th point is on the y-axis of the form $(0,Q)$. Then we have to find $N$ points of the form $(P_1,0),(P_2,0),\ldots,(P_N,0)$ such that $\sqrt{Q^2+P_i^2}$ is an integer for $i=1,\ldots,N$.

In other words it's enough to find a $Q$ that is part of at least $N$ Pythagorean triples.
All Pythagorean triples are of the form
$$
a = 2uv,~ b = u^2-v^2\text{ and }c = u^2+v^2
$$
for some positive integers $u$ and $v$ with $u>v$. Let's say we aim for $Q$ being the part of the Pythagorean triple that is of the form $2uv$. We just need to find a number that can be written as $2uv$ in at least $N$ different ways. Can you find such a number for any $N$? (Hint: There are many examples like $Q=2^{2n+2}$)